# Alternative debug output for node/vscode, while building a terminal based visualization

Tags: node.js, debugging, terminal, visual-studio-code, blessed

i'm developing a terminal based app with Node, and i'm using the terminal as output of a Blessed.js visualization.
So, i can't use the terminal to console.log thing for debug.
Does node offer an alternative debug output? I'm using VSCode.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In package.json add in scripts section:

```
 "scripts": {
    "debug": "node --nolazy --inspect-brk=9229 main.js"
  },
```

In vscode launch.json add:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach",
            "port": 9229
        }
    ]
}
```

Now:

First run blessed app with `npm run debug`

In 2nd step run vscode debugger with F5

You will see both blessed app interface and debugger in vscode.

Works for me ;)